# Possible Bug when rendering markups to canvas

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

we encountered a (possible) bug regarding the MarkupExtension that seems to only happen in Safari (MacOS + Mobile).
Our situation is that we make a screenshot of the viewer with the built-in functionality and then use the `markupExtension.renderToCanvas` method to render all currently drawn markups on top of the screenshot on the canvas before exporting it as a blob again.
The same idea is basically outlined in this article as well: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups

Now it's the case that this works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but for all Safari based browsers, the `markupExtension.renderToCanvas` method seems to not render any existing markups to the given canvas, no visible errors thrown.
Are there any known issues or are we doing something wrong?

I try to keep it short, so this is the just outline of our code that handles the described task, omitting the (successful) screenshot part:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('someId');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.drawImage(screenshotFromViewer, 0, 0, width, height);

markupExtension.renderToCanvas(ctx, () => {
    // callback: markups should be rendered to canvas
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been able to confirm that in Safari browsers the SVG rendering to canvas really isn't working. Let me bring this to the engineering team.

Comment: @PetrBroz thanks for your response! Please let me know when or if a bugfix is on the way - so we can update our customers, as it concerns everyone using our forge viewer implementation on the ipad.